# Java Agent integrarlo en un contendor

Tags: java

Tengo una duda teorica sobre los Java Agent, habitualmente los Java Agents son integrados siguiendo un codigo como este (o integrados por codigo, cosa que no me interesa,o 0 dependencia)

```
java -jar -javaagent myJavaAgent myProgram.jar
```

Mi idea es crear un contendor de Docker que herede de un contendore de OpenJDK y carge el agente previo a la ejecución del usuario

Contenedor Diseñado

```
FROM openjdk:7
RUN java //CARGAR MI JAVA AGENT
```

El contenedor del usuario que lo use

```
FROM personalJDK:7
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

Entiendo totalmente el problema de seguridad que implica utilizar esta forma, pero sería transparente para el usuario y no debería ocuparse de implementaciones.